# Configure Apache2 + PHP extentions (Centos6 + httpd)

Tags: php, apache2, centos

I'm trying to get PHP up and running in my httpd (Centos), so far I was able to get the php page running with the php code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, But instead of displaying the php details, it simple shows the plain PHP text.

After I did some research I found that even though I installed php, it might not loading the php modules correctly so I did the following changes

```
#/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

LoadModule php5_module  modules/libphp5.so
AddHandler php5-script  .php 

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

AddType text/html   .php

AddType application/x-httpd-php-source phps
```

but still the result is same :(, when I'm restarting the servers it says

```
[sameera@sameera ~]$ sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: [Mon Mar 04 12:09:07 2013] [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

I'm on `centos6`, `httpd`, `php-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed php using the system package manager(yum)? If yes then in conf.d folder of your apache configuration directory there's probably a separate file for php configuration where there already is a `LoadModule php5_module  modules/libphp5.so` line. What the error message says is that you are trying to load an already loaded module.

You should probably delete all your added config lines and if there's something wrong with your config you should fix it in the mentioned dedicated-for-php config file. After that do a restart and see the apache log if the module has been successfully loaded and try and see if `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` started working